# Enforce the return type of a function based on a property in its parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

As demonstrated in the self-contained snippet below ([or here on Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20These%20are%20from%20a%20library%0D%0Aexport%20declare%20type%20ActionCreator%3CT%20extends%20string%20%3D%20string%3E%20%3D%20(%0D%0A%20%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D%0D%0A)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Aexport%20declare%20type%20ActionCreatorMap%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20ActionType%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aexport%20declare%20type%20ActionType%3C%0D%0A%20%20ActionCreatorOrMap%0D%0A%3E%20%3D%20ActionCreatorOrMap%20extends%20ActionCreator%0D%0A%20%20%3F%20ReturnType%3CActionCreatorOrMap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20ActionCreatorOrMap%20extends%20object%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20ActionCreatorMap%3CActionCreatorOrMap%3E%5Bkeyof%20ActionCreatorOrMap%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20My%20stuff%20starts%20here%3A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20GameActionTypes%20%3D%20%22type1%22%20%7C%20%22type2%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20GameplayAction%3CT%20extends%20string%2C%20P%2C%20R%3E%20%3D%20P%20extends%20void%0D%0A%20%20%3F%20%7B%20type%3A%20T%3B%20returnType%3A%20R%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20T%3B%20payload%3A%20P%3B%20returnType%3A%20R%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20action%3CR%20%3D%20void%3E()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20function%3CT%20extends%20GameActionTypes%2C%20P%20%3D%20undefined%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3F%3A%20P%0D%0A%20%20)%3A%20GameplayAction%3CT%2C%20P%2C%20R%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20type%2C%20payload%20%7D%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20action1%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20action()(%22type1%22%2C%20%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20action2%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20action%3C%7B%20foo%3A%20%22bar%22%20%7D%3E()(%22type2%22%2C%20%7B%20c%3A%203%2C%20e%3A%204%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20gameActions%20%3D%20typeof%20action1%20%7C%20typeof%20action2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20narrows%20a%20tagged%20union%20by%20a%20tag%0D%0Aexport%20type%20FindByTag%3CUnion%2C%20Tag%3E%20%3D%20Union%20extends%20Tag%20%3F%20Union%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20ok%2C%20so%20these%20work%20fine%0D%0Atype%20TEST1%20%3D%20FindByTag%3CActionType%3CgameActions%3E%2C%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22type1%22%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20TEST2%20%3D%20FindByTag%3CActionType%3CgameActions%3E%2C%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22type2%22%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20executeAction%3CT%20extends%20GameActionTypes%3E(%0D%0A%20%20action%3A%20ActionType%3CgameActions%3E%0D%0A)%3A%20FindByTag%3CActionType%3CgameActions%3E%2C%20%7B%20type%3A%20T%20%7D%3E%5B%22returnType%22%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(action.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22type1%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(action.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22type2%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20THIS%20should%20fail!!!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20I%20want%20this%20return%20type%20to%20be%20enforced%20as%20%7Bfoo%3A%20%22bar%22%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)), I'd like to enforce return types on a function based on the `returnType` prop of the `action` argument. However, I want to enforce that the `returnType` is the correct `returnType` for *that* `action`, not just the `returnType` of any `action`.
Scroll down to the bottom of the snippet to see what I mean :)

```
// These are from a library
export declare type ActionCreator<T extends string = string> = (
  ...args: any[]
) => {
  type: T;
};
export declare type ActionCreatorMap<T> = { [K in keyof T]: ActionType<T[K]> };
export declare type ActionType<
  ActionCreatorOrMap
> = ActionCreatorOrMap extends ActionCreator
  ? ReturnType<ActionCreatorOrMap>
  : ActionCreatorOrMap extends object
    ? ActionCreatorMap<ActionCreatorOrMap>[keyof ActionCreatorOrMap]
    : never;

// My stuff starts here:
type GameActionTypes = "type1" | "type2";

type GameplayAction<T extends string, P, R> = P extends void
  ? { type: T; returnType: R }
  : { type: T; payload: P; returnType: R };

function action<R = void>() {
  return function<T extends GameActionTypes, P = undefined>(
    type: T,
    payload?: P
  ): GameplayAction<T, P, R> {
    return { type, payload } as any;
  };
}

const action1 = () => action()("type1", { a: 1, b: 2 });
const action2 = () => action<{ foo: "bar" }>()("type2", { c: 3, e: 4 });

type gameActions = typeof action1 | typeof action2;

// narrows a tagged union by a tag
export type FindByTag<Union, Tag> = Union extends Tag ? Union : never;

// ok, so these work fine
type TEST1 = FindByTag<ActionType<gameActions>, { type: "type1" }>;
type TEST2 = FindByTag<ActionType<gameActions>, { type: "type2" }>;

export function executeAction<T extends GameActionTypes>(
  action: ActionType<gameActions>
): FindByTag<ActionType<gameActions>, { type: T }>["returnType"] {
  if (action.type === "type1") {
    // This is good, the return type is enforced as `void`
    return;
  } else if (action.type === "type2") {
    //////////////// THIS should fail!!!
    // I want this return type to be enforced as {foo: "bar"}
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript won't narrow type parameters (see [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085)) via type guards.  That means the check `action.type === "type1"` might narrow `action.type`, but it doesn't narrow `T`, so the return type is still something like the union type `void | {foo: "bar"}`.

So you've got to work around it.  One way is to manually assert the return type in each type guarded clause:

```
type Ret<T extends GameActionTypes> = 
  FindByTag<ActionType<gameActions>, {type: T}>["returnType"];

export function executeAction<T extends GameActionTypes>(
  action: ActionType<gameActions>
): Ret<T> {
  if (action.type === "type1") {
    type R = Ret<typeof action.type>;
    return undefined as R; // okay
  } else if (action.type === "type2") {
    type R = Ret<typeof action.type>;
    return undefined as R; // error
  }
}
```

Note that the local type alias `R` is different in each guarded clause, and the assertion succeeds in one case and fails in the other.  I'm not sure if anyone has a type-safe solution easier than that.

---

#### UPDATE

So, I didn't realize that the `action` argument was not generic (I was too focused on the question about the return type inside the implementation).  That means you had two problems: inferring the right type of the return value in the implementation, *and* inferring the right type of the return value when calling the function.  Let's tackle the latter now.

First, if you want to infer different generic types based on function arguments, you need that argument to be a generic type also.  The best results are when the argument type is the same as the generic type parameter (and not some complicated function of the type parameter).  So let's do that:

```
export function executeAction<A extends ActionType<gameActions>>(
  action: A
): A["returnType"] {
  const actionUnion: ActionType<gameActions> = action; // remove generic
  if (actionUnion.type === "type1") {
    type R =  Ret<typeof actionUnion.type>
    return undefined as R;
  } else if (action.type === "type2") {
    type R =  Ret<typeof actionUnion.type>
    return undefined as R;
  }
}
```

Note how the action is given type `A`, and the return value is therefore just `A['returnType']`.  From the caller's perspective this is now pretty straightforward and should work how you expect:

```
declare const t1: TEST1;
const ret1 = executeAction(t1); // void
declare const t2: TEST2;
const ret2 = executeAction(t2); // {foo: "bar"}
```

The implementation of the function needed some tweaking... specifically, the generic is now `A`, the type of the action, instead of `T`, the type of the action's `type` property.  Narrowing is even less easy to accomplish.  The fix is to assign `action` to a non-generic variable `actionUnion` which is just the union type that `A` extends.  Then, the narrowing with `return undefined as Ret<typeof actionUnion.type>` works as (frustratingly as) before.

Comment: This is pretty great! it's frustrating that typescript doesn't support my use case right now, but this workaround is good enough. I'll accept your answer in a day or so if nobody comes up with a better solution

Comment: this works for enforcing that I return the right value, but doesn't appear to set the correct return type for the function depending on its parameters.